# How to return from closure?

Tags: swift

How can I return from closure in swift?

```
func closure(result: (Int -> Void)) {
    var next = 1

    while (true) {
        result(next)
    }
}
```

This is the invocation of the function

```
closure() { result in
    // here I need to return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no return from the `while` loop in the question. In order to return there must be some conditional statement that will exit the while loop, something like:

```
while (true) {
   result(next)
   if something == false {
       break;
   }
}
```

or:

```
var i = 0
while (true) {
    if i++ == 4 {
        break;
    }
    print(i)
}
```

or:

```
var i = 0
while (i <
    print(i)
}
```